# How do I add a body onload javascript function for a create content page in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6

I want assign certain values to some of the cck fields through Java script while the form is loaded. I think it is best to use the body/ form onload attribute. But how do i define that in drupal? Could someone help me with this or a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

As with many other tasks, Drupal has its own 'way' of handling JavaScript functionality within a site. It needs a little bit of learning and 'getting used to', but pays of in the long run.

Start with [JavaScript in Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/121997) and work through the articles linked from there. Also, don't miss [this overview of the JavaScript API](http://drupal.org/node/205296).